# what does "max_user_history_length": "200", default aws personalize - personalized ranking recipe hyper parameter means?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

aws personalize loads the below hyper parameter by default for personalized ranking recipe.
"max_user_history_length": "200"
But there is no explanation for this hyper parameter in the documentation. Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this parameter was introduced with a new feature for filtering recommendations?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/filter.html
In docs you can find, that "Amazon Personalize filters recommendations based on the most recent 200 historical and 100 new interaction events recorded in a user's Interactions dataset.". The number matches, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As per the document the filter is something to be applied for getting recommendations with any recipe. But "max_user_history_length": "200" -> this shows as hyper parameter only for personalize-ranking native recipe. So does this mean recent 200 records are considered for reranking the items for user by personalize ranking recipe?